# Array has elements but length is 0

Tags: arrays, typescript

I use an array which contains separate arrays and push objects in it.

My push looks like:

```
this.storeFilesService.base64files.filetype1.push({name: file.name, base64: str});
```

After I push an object into the subarray I log the array to the console.
console.log

```
(this.storeFilesService.base64files.filetype1);
```

Console output is:

```
[]
|-> 0: {name: "filename.pdf", base64: "JVBERi"}
```

But when I log the length of the array to the console the output is 0.

```
console.log(this.storeFilesService.base64files.filytype1.length);  -> 0
```

I am trying to check if the subarray contains objects, but my if clause seem to fail, cause of the length.

The oboce code is set in an angular onInit / constructor method.
Befor this i execute an async promise  in the last component within the onDestroy method. I think all promises should have been resolved when i reach the above code.

Why is this behaviour?

Update:
Tried a JSON console log

```
console.log('Array : ', this.storeFilesService.base64files.filytype1, JSON.stringify(this.storeFilesService.base64files.filytype1));
```

JSON -> []
Object -> same as above, contains the object.

How is this even possible?

Comment: any chance to reproduce it in a plunkr or similar? because without the context is pretty difficult to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to be related to the live console by chrome. The value was updated by chrome in the console even after it was already printed.